# How to find the closest array element to another array element x where y is closer if it is after x in the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

EDIT:
So I want a function that takes in an array e.g. `['foo',2,'bar',4,5]` and an element e.g. `'bar'` and returns the closest element. In this case it should return `4` (as opposed to `2` because `4` is after `'bar'`).

Whats a simple way to do this?....looking for something that uses a functional style like underscore.js...

I know i can do it the brute force way (iteration) but wondering if there's a clever way (like mod size of array math) that makes this one or two lines.

Comment: I think you need to rephrase your question.  Can you express your examples in terms of function calls and return values?

Comment: yes this was definitely unclear... edited the question!

Comment: I don't understand why you favor `4` over `2` or why you can't do something like `my_array[i+1]`

Comment: No, there is no built-in JavaScript method to return this "closest" value; the reason being that it's almost trivial to obtain through [the usual methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

Comment: i know it's trivial...but im looking for the cleanest implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
function closest(arr, val) {
    var idx = arr.indexOf(val);
    if(idx < 0 || arr.length === 1) { return null; }
    return (idx+1) < arr.length ? arr[idx+1] : arr[idx-1]
}
```

Comment: There is a small bug, it should be `if (idx < 0 || arr.length === 1)` because indexOf returns -1 when it can't find the value in the array. Also arrays in JS are 0-indexed so it's entirely possible for `idx` to be 0 and in that case you should be returning arr[1] so long as arr.length >= 2.

Comment: @Shashank Gupta thanks, fixed `idx < 0`.  I think I'm okay in your other case, if idx === 0 and length is not 1 I return arr[1] as intended.

Comment: I only had one "case" lol :) With `idx <= 0` you weren't returning arr[1], you were returning null. Anyways +1.